# ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to Position2D?

Tags: c#, json

При десериализации объекта из JSON строки выводится ошибка:

```
Could not cast or convert from System.String to Position2D
```

То есть невозможно преобразовать строковое представление в класс Position2D.

А можно ли как то в этом классе что то добавить, чтобы он мог создаваться из строки? Сериализуется он успешно, а вот обратно не хочет.

```
public struct Position2D
{
    public int x;
    public int y;


    override public String ToString()
    {
        return x.ToString() + "x" + y.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Но сам json и код, с помощью которого вы его десереализуете, вы конечно же не покажете? Совет наугад: попробуйте создать конструктор, принимающий строку.

Comment: Как минимум укажите библиотеку - Newtonsoft JSON, System.Text.Json, другое.

Comment: Newtonsoft JSON. Как я понял тут нужен explicit operator для такого копирования.